# Flask GET request are sent to wrong path resulting on 404

Tags: python, flask

I am having an issue with my flask app.

I have the following code:

```
@app.route("/note")
def note():
  return render_template("note.html")

@app.route("/notes/<notename>")
def notes(notename):
  return render_template("note.html")
```

Both should return the same content but the issue is that when the app tries to make a GET request to get js and css files for that page the one with the route /notes/ is not able to obtain those js and css files becouse the GET request is pointing to the wrong path.

I will show an example:

When I navigate to example.com/note the output is:

```
[18/Jul/2020 08:59:11] "GET /note HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[18/Jul/2020 08:59:11] "GET /static/css/layout/layout.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jul/2020 08:59:11] "GET /static/js/notes/notes.js HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[18/Jul/2020 08:59:11] "GET /static/css/notes/notes.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[18/Jul/2020 08:59:11] "GET /static/css/notes/buttons.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
```

and everything works fine.

BUT when I go to example.com/notes/somethinghere the page loads without JS or CSS styling and in the console I get this:

```
[18/Jul/2020 09:01:34] "GET /notes/somethinghere HTTP/1.1" 200 -
[18/Jul/2020 09:01:35] "GET /notes/static/css/notes/notes.css HTTP/1.1" 404  -
[18/Jul/2020 09:01:35] "GET /notes/static/js/notes/notes.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[18/Jul/2020 09:01:35] "GET /notes/static/css/notes/buttons.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
[18/Jul/2020 09:01:35] "GET /notes/static/js/notes/notes.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

The issue is that the GET request starts with /notes so it doesnt find the folder where JS and CSS files are thus not loading it.
Some dirty fixes I have come up are creating a notes folder and clone the js and css files there so it founds them or just removing /notes from the url path but none of those are even close to perfect.

Is there a way to change the path so it doesnt start with /notes when going to example.com/notes/somethinghere?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably exists within `notes.html`.

I'm guessing you include the path without the leading `/`:

```
<link href='static/css/somefile.css'>
```

Whereas you should be doing something like:

```
<link href='/static/css/somefile.css'>
```

Of course in Flask you could use the `url_for` function to generate this dynamically:

```
<link href'{{ url_for('static', filename='css/somefile.css') }}'>
```

Comment: Thas not the problem, the CSS file is reached when I go to /note as the path is correct. But it doesnt reach it when I go to /notes/notename becouse the GET request to reach the CSS file changes from `/static/css/notes/notes.css` to `/notes/static/css/notes/notes.css`

Comment: @MarioML Werid behaviour.  Unless you're doing something funny with template loading, `url_for` should always render the same path, regardless of the depth of paths in the request URL: [https://pastebin.com/3hpx4m7w](https://pastebin.com/3hpx4m7w).  Can you please edit your Q to show the relevant lines from your `notes.html`.